# php error log for class files in different directory

Tags: php, error-handling

Please excuse an, at least initially, high level question about logging php script errors.  Is it a valid expectation that php error_log will record errors in a class file that is in a different directory to the main php script?

I have two php files

```
pages/add_edit_xxxx.php
```

and

```
class/class_xxxx.php
```

add_edit_xxxx.php depends on public functions in the class file

If I deliberately introduce an error in pages/add_edit_xxxx.php then pages/error_log correctly records the line number of the error

If I deliberately introduce an error in class/class_xxxx.php then class/error_log sometimes records the error and sometimes remains unchanged

I do not have access to php.ini
But I guess that the settings are OK as sometimes class/error_log records the error but more often than not it does not log the error.

I have this in a settings file:

```
ini_set("include_path", '/home/xxxx/php:' . ini_get("include_path") );  
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
@session_start();
```

Called at the start of pages/add_edit_xxxx.php

```
include_once("settings.php");
```

I hope this is enough to enable thoughts on whether it is a valid expectation that the errors in the class file should be reliably caught and logged.  At the moment I cannot recreate a scenario when a log was created - but this is an example of class/error_log entry that was written yesterday

```
[20-Oct-2021 19:00:48 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$tempRS' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxxx.com/class/class_xxxx.php on line 36
```

If I remove the deliberately inserted errors (for example a missing semi-colon) then the page functions well.

Thank you

Comment: Use if statement to do validation before sending values to server, then  you wont face to unexpected `$tempRS` errors.

Comment: Thank you @dlk but the reason I want to catch the errors is to help with debugging sometimes lengthy scripts

Answer (score 0):

resolved by updating this line in the settings file:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

to

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```